# Unexpected results for KNN query with filtering on a nested field

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

I have an index:

```
"properties": {
    "id": {"type": "text"},
    "date": {"type": "text"},
    "title": {"type": "text"},
    "users": {"type": "nested"},
    "ideas": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "vector": {
                "type": "knn_vector",
                "dimension": 384
            },
            "timestamp": {"type": "integer"},
            "content": {
                "type": "keyword", 
            },
        }
    }
}
```

The following query searches for ideas with high similarity to a given vector:

```
body={
    "_source": {
        "includes": [
            "title",
            "users",
            "ideas._score"
        ]
    },
    "size": 1,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "ideas",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "script_score": {
                                            "query": {
                                                "match_all": {}
                                            },
                                            "script": {
                                                "source": "knn_score",
                                                "lang": "knn",
                                                "params": {
                                                    "field": "ideas.vector",
                                                    "query_value": query_vector,
                                                    "space_type": "cosinesimil"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It returns the following in the output:

```
{"hits": "_id": "kHCOaIkBUHe9xr-u09Xr", "_score": 1.1901431, "_source": {"title": "doc1", "users": [{"id": "user1"}]}}
```

Now, I modify the above query to only consider documents to which a particular user has access:

```
body={
    "_source": {
        "includes": [
            "title",
            "users",
            "ideas._score"
        ]
    },
    "size": 1,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "users",
                        "query": {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "users.id": user_id
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "ideas",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "script_score": {
                                            "query": {
                                                "match_all": {}
                                            },
                                            "script": {
                                                "source": "knn_score",
                                                "lang": "knn",
                                                "params": {
                                                    "field": "ideas.vector",
                                                    "query_value": query_vector,
                                                    "space_type": "cosinesimil"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When I pass to this query "user1" as the user of interest, I expect to see the same output as for the first query. However, I see something different:

```
{"hits": "_id": "kXCOaIkBUHe9xr-u2tV1", "_score": 2.866434, "_source": {"title": "doc2", "users": [{"id": "user1"}]}}
```

In fact, with this filtering,  the scores are high even for absolutely unrelated queries. In addition, the scores are supposed to be between 1 and 2, so that the score 2.866434 should never happen.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I would add the first nested constraint on `user.id` in a `bool/filter` section instead of `bool/must` as it shouldn't contribute to scoring. Also use `term` instead of `match_phrase` which is not meant for exact matching on ids

Comment: @Val How do I force it to perform filtering **before** executing the knn search?

Comment: Just move the first constraint outside of `bool/must` into `bool/filter`

Comment: @Val It works! I would still like to understand how filtering in `bool/must` affected the scores.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the first nested constraint on `user.id` in a `bool/filter` section instead of `bool/must` as it shouldn't contribute to scoring, like this:

```
body={
    "_source": {
        "includes": [
            "title",
            "users",
            "ideas._score"
        ]
    },
    "size": 1,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "users",
                        "query": {
                            "term": {
                                "users.id": user_id
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "ideas",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "script_score": {
                                            "query": {
                                                "match_all": {}
                                            },
                                            "script": {
                                                "source": "knn_score",
                                                "lang": "knn",
                                                "params": {
                                                    "field": "ideas.vector",
                                                    "query_value": query_vector,
                                                    "space_type": "cosinesimil"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Any constraint you add to `bool/must` contributes to scoring by design. if you don't want your additional constraint(s) to contribute to scoring, you can simply add them to the filter section instead.

Similarly, you can also add your additional constraint inside the `script_score` query in order to reduce the document set that the knn search has to process:

```
body={
    "_source": {
        "includes": [
            "title",
            "users",
            "ideas._score"
        ]
    },
    "size": 1,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "ideas",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "script_score": {
                                            "query": {
                                               "term": {
                                                  "users.id": user_id
                                               }                                                
                                            },
                                            "script": {
                                                "source": "knn_score",
                                                "lang": "knn",
                                                "params": {
                                                    "field": "ideas.vector",
                                                    "query_value": query_vector,
                                                    "space_type": "cosinesimil"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "contributes to scoring by design". In what way does it contribute? How does it cause the score to be outside of the normal range for cosine similarity?

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you also try the second query?

Comment: My query is not quite a bit different, so I inserted it where it seemed most appropriate. I got the error: `script_score query does not support [query]`. Is the second query supposed to be more efficient than the first one? Also, you did not answer my question about the exact way the score is affected.

Comment: Weird about the error message you get because your initial script_score query already had `match_all` query in it.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't included `query` two times in the script score query? Can you look at my answer again?

Comment: If you like, we can take it to chat. I'll show you my current query and you'll propose how you think it should be changed. Then I'll try to run it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm off until the 30th